# Compiler could not generate default constructor for the class Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

class Node
{
  public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node(int data)
  {
    data = data;
  }
};

class LinkedList
{
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
  int n,data;
  Node nod;
  public:
  void cll()
  {
    cout<<"Enter the no. of nodes"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      cin>>data;
      nod = new Node(data);
      if(head == NULL)
      {
        head = nod;
        tail = nod;
      }
      else
      {
        tail->next = nod;
        tail = nod;
      }
    }
  }
};

void main()
{
  LinkedList l1;
  l1.cll();
}
```

When i compile this code i get an error which say ***compiler could not generate default constructor for the class.***

And if i define a constructor then it shows this error ***cannot find default constructor to initialize base class c++.***

How can i fix this error plz help.

Comment: Your `Node` class doesn't have a default constructor but you use it (uninitialized)  in the derived class. Also what do **you** think the line `data = data;` will do? I know what it *doesn't* do.

Comment: The error message says exactly what is wrong. `LinkedList` cannot initialize its `nod` member variable if `Node` does not have default constructor.

Comment: There are more errors than that. And you should upgrade your compiler to one from this millennium.

Comment: `void main()` is illegal in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The standard says:

If no user-declared constructors of any kind are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a default constructor as an inline public member of its class.

Since you have provided a constructor which takes an int no default constructors were generated.

```
class Node
{
  public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node(int data) { // here is your custom constructor
    data = data;
  }
};
```

Then you create an object:

```
Node nod; // no constructor Node() provided - this is the error you get
Node nod(1); // will work, since you have provided Node(int data) constructor
```

But obviously according to your code you should declare the pointer to Node instead of creating an object.

```
Node *nod = new Node(1);
```

And better redefine your constructor to use member initializer list:

```
class Node
{
  public:
  int data;
  Node *next;

  Node(int data) : data{data} { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The compilable  code:

```
#include<iostream>//change here
//#include<conio.h> //change here

class Node
{
  public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
  Node(int data)
  {
    data = data;
  }
};

class LinkedList
{
  Node *head;
  Node *tail;
  int n,data;
  Node *nod;  //change here
  public:
  void cll()
  {
    cout<<"Enter the no. of nodes"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      cin>>data;
      nod = new Node(data);
      if(head == NULL)
      {
        head = nod;
        tail = nod;
      }
      else
      {
        tail->next = nod;
        tail = nod;
      }
    }
  }
};

int main() //change here
{
  LinkedList l1;
  l1.cll();
}
```

Comment: Note that good answers not only present fixed code, but also provide an explanation about all the fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This line causes the error

```
Node nod;
```

Instead, you should write

```
Node* nod;
```

Anyway, your code has a lot of errors causing the program to crash. Probably you are learning from an Outdated C++ course.

First of all use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include<iostream.h>`. The header `<conio.h>` actually is not needed in this program.
In the other hand, try to learn about smart pointers instead a C style pointers. So, your `Node` class should look like this, if you want to do all in the same file. It is strongly recommended separating the declarations and implementations in `.h` and `.cpp` respectively

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node
{
public:
    
    int data;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> nextNode;
    inline Node() : nextNode { nullptr }{};
    inline Node(int data) : data{ data }, nextNode{nullptr} {}; //member initializer list
};
```

Also is a good practice to use member initializer list on the constructor.

The LinkedList should look something like this

```
class LinkedList
{
    std::shared_ptr<Node> head;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> tail;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> currentNode;
    int n, data;
public:
    LinkedList() : head{ nullptr }, tail{ nullptr }, currentNode{ nullptr } {};
    void cll()
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the no. of nodes" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the data for the " << i + 1 << " node" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> data; 
            currentNode = std::make_shared<Node>(data);
            if (!head) // head == nullptr is redundant
            {
                head = currentNode;
                tail = currentNode;
            }
            else
            {
                tail->nextNode = currentNode;
                tail = currentNode;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

To finish, the `void main()` is not allowed in modern C++ instead you should use `int main()`

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList l1;
    l1.cll();
}
```

This code compiles correctly, but I highly recommend you to change the source from where you are learning C++

One more thing, use `nullptr` insted of `NULL`

Comment: Thanks for you help. Could you suggest some good sources for learning C++.

Comment: You are welcome. Some resources I used to learn C++, in addition the college, were the book "Sams Teach Yourself C++ in One Hour a Day", the YouTube channel "The Cherno" and the Udemy course "Beginning C++ Programming - From Beginner to Beyond". I hope my solution has helped you. Have a nice day!